# REST API Design - Multiple Endpoints

Tags: rest

I am currently writing a REST API specification for an assignment.

This question concerns about routing and how to design resources and endpoints.
Is it better for a resource to have multiple endpoints like this:

```
Method | Resource              | Description
-------+-----------------------+-------------------------
POST   | /cash-card/create     | Create a prepaid account
POST   | /cash-card/:id/pay    | Pay some service
PUT    | /cash-card/:id/topup  | Top up cash card
DELETE | /cash-card/:id/delete | Delete prepaid Account
```

Or have one endpoint and differentiate with the HTTP Method like this:

```
Method | Resource       | Description
-------+----------------+-------------------------
POST   | /cash-card/    | Create a prepaid account
POST   | /cash-card/:id | Pay some service
PUT    | /cash-card/:id | Top up cash card
DELETE | /cash-card/:id | Delete prepaid Account
```

In both versions I use Path Parameters to identify the resource.

Is this just a design choice?
Or is there some convention on how to design resources?

Thank you, I would appreciate any help.

Comment: the second one is best practice.  read some articles about how to write REST APIs, you will get a better understanding.

Comment: Normally you make use of HTTP methods to save you the need to have multiple URLs which also many people remind of RMI times and strictly speaking are not very REST-y. So, your second example is definitely better than your first but POST and PUT again rather look like RMI than REST because normally you don't top-up a card but rather create a payment which itself then tops-up the *value* of the card.

Comment: I voted to close as primarily opinion based. In a REST architecture the form of the URI isn't of relevance. Clients shouldn't parse URIs to extract information as server's are free to change their URI namespace anytime they want to. Furthermore, clients shouldn't attempt to retrieve a type from the URI as REST doesn't have [typed resources](http://soabits.blogspot.com/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html) but should rely on content-type negotiation. Some people will claim that verbs shouldn't be present in "RESTful URIs" though this is everything but true as peers shouldn't care!

Comment: FYI there's no difference between 'design choices' and 'conventions'. They're both options that a person or group decided upon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this just a design choice?

No, there are real trade-offs you are making.

HTTP is an application protocol, whose application domain is the transfer of documents over a network ([Webber, 2011](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m8s)).  `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `PATCH`, `DELETE` are all requests with the semantics of a document store: "find the document with this key, and do something to it".

Your "REST API", therefore, is a facade intended to make your domain application protocol look like a dumb document store.

The advantage you get in doing this, is that you can leverage a bunch of work that has already been done producing general purpose components (browsers, caches, indexing spiders, and so on).

One example of this work is [cache-invalidation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4); general purpose components know that a successful response to `POST /cash-card/:id` invalidates the representation(s) in the cache (presumably after `GET /cash-card/:id`).

When we instead `POST /cash-card/:id/pay`, we don't get the invalidation for free, because general-purpose clients do not assume that there is any relationship between `/cash-card/:id/pay` and `/cash-card/:id`.  The identifiers are semantically opaque.

What this means is, if we have a resource (/foo) that might be modified several different ways (different domain semantics), they might all look like `POST /foo`.  On the server, we would then need to examine the HTTP request to discover the rest of the domain semantics.

If you imagine doing this on the web, you might have a single `/cash-card/:id` resource, and then a bunch of *forms* that you use to construct other interesting messages; `/cash-card/:id/pay` for the form to make a payment, `/cash-card/:id/topup` for the form to put more money on the card, and so on.  All of these forms would submit their requests to `/cash-card/:id`, because that's the resource you want to invalidate if the change is successful.

Preferring "no caching" or "customized caching" to "general purpose caching" is perfectly valid in some circumstances.  Nice properties come with the cost of conforming to constraints; what you have to work out is which combination of properties and constraints is going to offer the best profit.

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort that you have put into the answer. It really helped me understand the approaches and which one to choose. 

I read up on some REST API conventions and visited some REST APIs of some companies for example spotify and twitter to help me understand the design better.

I will use the second approach I mentioned because of the cache-invalidation that you mentioned.